# Create custom dplyr data transformation function in R

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I need to repeat an operation many times for a different combinations of two different variables (trying to create data for stacked barplots showing percentage. Could anyone turn the code below into a function (of dataset, and the two variables x and y) in order to create the new data sets quickly? Or give me some good reference or link for learning about functions and dplyr. Thanks.

```
 dat = df %>% 
   select(x, y) %>% 
   group_by(x, y) %>% 
   summarise(n = n()) %>% 
   mutate(percentage = round(n/sum(n)*100, 1)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   group_by(x) %>% 
   mutate(pos = cumsum(percentage) - (0.5 * percentage)) %>% 
   ungroup()  
   return(dat)
```

Comment: Have a look at: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html

Comment: good reading, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, step-by-step explanations can be found here: [dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)
This guide will provide explanation of `quo()` function and `!!` symbols.

For your example you can create a function like so:

```
df1<- data.frame(x1 = c(rep(3,5), rep(7,2)), 
                y1 = c(rep(2,4), rep(5,3)))

my.summary <- function(df, x, y){
  df %>% 
    select(!!x, !!y) %>% 
    group_by(!!x, !!y) %>% 
    summarise(n = n()) %>%
    mutate(percentage = round(n/sum(n)*100, 1)) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    group_by(!!x) %>% 
    mutate(pos = cumsum(percentage) - (0.5 * percentage)) %>% 
    ungroup() 
}

my.summary(df1, quo(x1), quo(y1))

# # A tibble: 3 x 5
#    x1    y1     n percentage   pos
# <dbl> <dbl> <int>      <dbl> <dbl>
#   1     3     2     4         80    40
#   2     3     5     1         20    90
#   3     7     5     2        100    50
```

Comment: Thank you, but when i add the mutate parts to the function it doesn't work anymore, could you extend your code to a full example?

Comment: Just did. See the answer

Comment: Great! I also started reading on Markus his suggestion, i'm starting to get it now.

Comment: Yes, the link is very helpful and I added it to the answer to make it better visible to everyone.